# What is the meaning of the `+`, `-` and ` ` signs that precedes `Done` when a background process ends?

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

**Question**

What are the meaning of the `+`, `-` and  signs that precedes `Done` when a background process ends?

**Examples of interest**

Code 1

```
(sleep 4s; echo first)&
(sleep 2s; echo second)&
(sleep 1s; echo third)&

[1]   Done                    ( sleep 4s; echo first )
[2]-  Done                    ( sleep 2s; echo second )
[3]+  Done                    ( sleep 1s; echo third )
```

Code 2

```
(echo first)&
(echo second)&
(echo third)&

[1]+  Done                    ( echo first )
[2]+  Done                    ( echo second )
[3]+  Done                    ( echo third )
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So here is my understanding of it:

1- Job flagged or having a `+` is the one that was sent to the background last.

2- Job flagged or having a `-` was sent to the background second last.

3- Other background jobs are not flagged.

Here is an example I just ran on my system

```
$bash: /singh/test1 &
[1] 9223
$bash:  /singh/test2 &
[2] 9226
$bash:  /singh/test3 &
[3] 9234
$bash:  /singh/test4 &
[4] 9237
$bash:  jobs
[1]   Running                 /singh/test &
[2]   Running                 /singh/test2 &
[3]-  Running                 /singh/test3 &
[4]+  Running                 /singh/test4 &
```

***I could see from man*** `bash`:

> There  are  a  number  of  ways  to refer to a job in the shell.  The character % introduces a job specification (jobspec).  Job
>   number n may be
>          referred to as %n.  A job may also be referred to using a prefix of the name used to start it, or using a substring that appears
>   in its  command
>          line.   For  example,  %ce  refers to a stopped ce job.  If a prefix matches more than one job, bash reports an error.  Using %?ce,
>   on the other
>          hand, refers to any job containing the string ce in its command line.  If the substring matches more than one job, bash reports an 
>   error.   The
>          symbols %% and %+ refer to the shell’s notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or
>   started in the
>          background.  The previous job may be referenced using %-.  If there is only a single job, %+ and %- can both be used to refer to
>   that  job.   In
>          output  pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous
>   job with a -.  A
>          single % (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to the current job.

Answer (score 5):

```
%+ : current job; last job stopped in foreground or started in background
%- : last/previous job
%% : same as +
```

`%+` not only displays for the change of status in a backgrounded job, but also for a foreground job, e.g., that has been suspended with `kill -STOP <pid>`.

```
$ sleep 10 
[1]+  Stopped    sleep 10

# by running kill -STOP 28105  on another terminal
```

See [Bash Job Control Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Basics) for more detail.

> Job number n may be referred to as ‘%n’. The symbols ‘%%’ and ‘%+’ refer to the shell’s notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or started in the background. A single ‘%’ (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to the current job. The previous job may be referenced using ‘%-’. If there is only a single job, ‘%+’ and ‘%-’ can both be used to refer to that job. In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a ‘+’, and the previous job with a ‘-’.

With multiple jobs running in the background, `bash` shows you the job, when its status has been changed and when it hits another `prompt`. To see the job immediately when job changes its status/terminated, one can use `set` builtin.

```
$ set -b
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 27866
$ sleep 10 &
[2] 27868
$  [1]-  Done                    sleep 10

[2]+  Done                    sleep 10
```